# Effect of aspect ratio in camera calibration using matlab calibration toolbox

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration

Currently I am using [Camera Calibration Toolbox in Matlab](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) for my camera calibration. The toolbox returns calibration parameters such as focal length, principle point, skew, and distortion. However, the issue is i when take a pictures at aspect ratio of 4:3.The toolbox give more accurate distortions.My first attachment having the image with aspect ratio of 4:3.The Width of the image is 3664 and height is 2740.The toolbox works perfectly.But when i use image with different aspect ratio like my second attachment with height of 3664 and width of 2740 pixels.The toolbox will give wrong distortions.i did not change any thing in toolbox.i just follow the instruction which is given by toolbox web.Does need to change in that procedure.please help me.mention if i am wrong.
Thanks in advance

i took nearly 100 images in each type for calibration ![enter image description here][2]
here is the link for images.
http://i44.tinypic.com/dxkcps.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Distortion parameters are values relative to image size.

http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/parameters.html
http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/eq2.gif

`Kc` is the distortion coefficient. Smaller image has smaller `r`. If you scale image, the coefficient will be proportionally (square) smaller.

Are you sure both images have the same resolution 3664x2740 as written?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.both images are same resolution.but in which height and width was direct opposite in two cameras.my board size is same for two cameras.i have one doubt my sqaure size is 200mm.In camera calibration toolbox ask me to enter the value of size of square like this ("Size dX of each square along the X direction").Can you tell unit value of the square?which value i am going enter 200 or else 0.2?

Comment: Those units only affect you when you decide to grab external matrices for those images (if you write 'mm', extrinsic matrix will grab the rotation&distance from camera to the first chessboard corner in 'mm' units, if 'm' then in meters... - it doesn't affect focal lenght, principal point and distortion coefficients). I'm used to 'mm'.

Tested generating calibrations with a) rotated image by 90deg, b) cropped image to the 3:4 ratio, in both cases some values just get swapped, but the overall result is similar.

Maybe JPEG compression is at fault?

Comment: Great Bronek. Now i'm cleared.But i try another one method,i captured one small chessboard images at 1 meter distance from the camera and captured some images using Big chessboard(5 times bigger than smaller one) at 5 meter distance from the camera.while both images are looking same size in images. i calibrated separately, now i got two different distortion parameters.since my size of each square was different for two chessboards.can you give me some suggestion.

Comment: Grab `GML Camera Calibration Toolbox` and do the calibration from it, check `pixel error` field. Images used for calibration are real or computer generated? You also may be getting very small distortions and they differ just because of those pixel errors.